# How to get nested (linked) Components in fewer requests over GraphQL

Tags: content-delivery, graphql

Is it possible to get linked content in the same GraphQL query?

For example, using the following query we can get back a page and components within its regions.

```
{
pagequery: page(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 7, pageId: 726) {
    itemId
    title
    url
    regions {
      name
      components {
        title
        ... on Component {
          itemId
          title
          content {
            ... on UntypedContent {
              data
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Question**: Is it possible to also get the data for linked Components in the same request, using a request with UntypedContent or otherwise (Semantic Content Models)?

Related to this:

1. GraphiQL shows that `data` is `UntypedContent:data: Map.` What is a `Map` in this context?
2. Is it possible to get specific fields out of a "map?" The documentation in GraphiQL describes UntypedContent as "Untyped content where all data is available in a Map structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by using Semantic Content Modelling. Here is a sample query with the corresponding output. Note how I can fetch all the content, including the image details.

```
{
  page(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 14, url: "/finance_articles.html") {
    publicationId
    itemId
    title
    regions {
      name
      components {
        itemId
        title
        ... on FinanceArticle {
          heading
          subHeading
          bodyText {
            html
          }
          numberField
          dateField
          image {
            ... on Image {
              title
              metadata {
                altText
              }
              variants {
                edges {
                  node {
                    url
                    downloadUrl
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          metadata {
            metadataField1
            financeArticleType {
              ... on Keyword {
                title
                description
                key
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "page": {
      "publicationId": 14,
      "itemId": 719,
      "title": "Finance Articles Page",
      "regions": [
        {
          "name": "Main",
          "components": [
            {
              "itemId": 718,
              "title": "Finance Article Sample 1",
              "heading": "Heading - Finance Article Sample 1",
              "subHeading": "Subheading - Finance Article Sample 1",
              "bodyText": {
                "html": "<p>Body Text content in Finance Article Sample 1.</p>"
              },
              "numberField": 11,
              "dateField": "2023-01-31T02:54:47.000",
              "image": {
                "title": "Finance Article Image 1",
                "metadata": {
                  "altText": "Alt Text - Finance Article Image 1"
                },
                "variants": {
                  "edges": [
                    {
                      "node": {
                        "url": "/media/skyline.jpg",
                        "downloadUrl": "http://localhost:8081/cd/api/binary/1/14/717"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "metadata": {
                "metadataField1": "Metadata value!",
                "financeArticleType": {
                  "title": "Internal Report",
                  "description": "Internal Report",
                  "key": "InternalReport"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "itemId": 720,
              "title": "Finance Article Sample 2",
              "heading": "Heading - Finance Article Sample 2",
              "subHeading": "Subheading - Finance Article Sample 2",
              "bodyText": {
                "html": "<p>Body Text content</p>\n<p>More content</p>"
              },
              "numberField": 1200,
              "dateField": "2022-12-29T02:54:47.000",
              "image": {
                "title": "Finance Article Image 2",
                "metadata": {
                  "altText": "Alt Text - Finance Article Image 2"
                },
                "variants": {
                  "edges": [
                    {
                      "node": {
                        "url": "/media/blueprint.jpg",
                        "downloadUrl": "http://localhost:8081/cd/api/binary/1/14/721"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "metadata": {
                "metadataField1": "Metadata content",
                "financeArticleType": {
                  "title": "End of Year Announcement",
                  "description": "End of Year Announcement",
                  "key": "EndOfYearResults"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't think you can (easily) achieve your goal by using untyped content/components. Semantic content modelling is the way to go.

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 and accepted, thanks @Phil!

Comment: For those interested in getting the typed content models as part of the page, please review and vote for this idea: https://community.rws.com/ideas/tridion-ideas/i/tridion-sites-ideas/expand-linked-nested-content-in-the-public-content-api.